# Header logo is very pixelated in Firefox but perfectly fine in Chrome/Safari, regardless of image file type

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, firefox

Having an issue with the header logo on a wordpress site. Logo appears incredibely pixelated on Firefox, but is smooth and appears as expected on Google Chrome and Safari. Even after trying .png, .svg, and even .jpg, the logo still appears very pixelated on Firefox browser. Even after scaling down/up the images resolution, still appears pixelated.

CSS attributes such as image-rendering have no effect on the image. Any reason why this would be, or any possible fixes for it?

[Comparison Photo between logo in FF and Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaNf2.jpg)

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Presumably, you can use `-moz-transform` as per this guide: https://wpza.net/wordpress-logo-appearing-pixelated-in-chrome/ — please, let me know?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS for the image:

```
image-rendering: auto;
```

Comment: As I said @Periplo, I have tried this with no avail.